# Azure Logic app read my approval email in form of HTML tags

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have created a Azure Logic app to read the email body and check for the condition - If the email body 1st line has the only word called "Approved", then trigger another process or else do nothing.

But when performing it, I could see the condition gets to false even though the mail has only Approved word in it accommodated with signatures in the bottom. After researching, I could see the email is being read like HTML tags. So i created two more variable to extract a part of this e-mail and check for condition.

EmailBodyTrimmed = trim(substring(toUpper(replace(replace(trim(variables('EmailBody')),' ',''),'.',''),),0,500))

EmailBodyTrimmedFinal = trim(substring(trim(replace(trim(variables('EmailBodyTrimmed')),' ','')),0,indexOf(replace(variables('EmailBodyTrimmed'),' ',''),'<')))

But nothing seems to give correct answer. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Can u please upload code version of your logicapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `Body Preview` to receive the body of the email:

[image]

According to my test results, it receives the text in non-HTML format, so you don't have to extract the body from the HTML text.

[image]

Then you only need to add a condition and use `starts with` to determine whether it starts with approved.

[image]

Of course, this premise is that your email body is in plain text format, if it is in excel format, you need to do other processing.